# How to check what port a pod is listening on with kubectl and not looking at the dockerFile?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a pod running and want to port forward so i can access the pod from the internal network.
I don't know what port it is listening on though, there is no service yet.

I describe the pod:

```
$ kubectl describe pod queue-l7wck 
Name:         queue-l7wck
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/192.168.64.3
Start Time:   Wed, 18 Dec 2019 05:13:56 +0200
Labels:       app=work-queue
              chapter=jobs
              component=queue
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           172.17.0.2
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.2
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/queue
Containers:
  queue:
    Container ID:   docker://13780475170fa2c0d8e616ba1a3b1554d31f404cc0a597877e790cbf01838e63
    Image:          gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64@sha256:1ecc9fb2c871302fdb57a25e0c076311b7b352b0a9246d442940ca8fb4efe229
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 18 Dec 2019 05:14:02 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-mbn5b (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-mbn5b:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-mbn5b
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age        From               Message
  ----    ------     ----       ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  <unknown>  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/queue-l7wck to minikube
  Normal  Pulling    31h        kubelet, minikube  Pulling image "gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue"
  Normal  Pulled     31h        kubelet, minikube  Successfully pulled image "gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue"
  Normal  Created    31h        kubelet, minikube  Created container queue
  Normal  Started    31h        kubelet, minikube  Started container queue
```

even the JSON has nothing:

```
$ kubectl get pods queue-l7wck -o json
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Pod",
    "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": "2019-12-18T03:13:56Z",
        "generateName": "queue-",
        "labels": {
            "app": "work-queue",
            "chapter": "jobs",
            "component": "queue"
        },
        "name": "queue-l7wck",
        "namespace": "default",
        "ownerReferences": [
            {
                "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
                "blockOwnerDeletion": true,
                "controller": true,
                "kind": "ReplicaSet",
                "name": "queue",
                "uid": "a9ec07f7-07a3-4462-9ac4-a72226f54556"
            }
        ],
        "resourceVersion": "375402",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/queue-l7wck",
        "uid": "af43027d-8377-4227-b366-bcd4940b8709"
    },
    "spec": {
        "containers": [
            {
                "image": "gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue",
                "imagePullPolicy": "Always",
                "name": "queue",
                "resources": {},
                "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
                "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
                "volumeMounts": [
                    {
                        "mountPath": "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount",
                        "name": "default-token-mbn5b",
                        "readOnly": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "enableServiceLinks": true,
        "nodeName": "minikube",
        "priority": 0,
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler",
        "securityContext": {},
        "serviceAccount": "default",
        "serviceAccountName": "default",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "tolerations": [
            {
                "effect": "NoExecute",
                "key": "node.kubernetes.io/not-ready",
                "operator": "Exists",
                "tolerationSeconds": 300
            },
            {
                "effect": "NoExecute",
                "key": "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable",
                "operator": "Exists",
                "tolerationSeconds": 300
            }
        ],
        "volumes": [
            {
                "name": "default-token-mbn5b",
                "secret": {
                    "defaultMode": 420,
                    "secretName": "default-token-mbn5b"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": {
        "conditions": [
            {
                "lastProbeTime": null,
                "lastTransitionTime": "2019-12-18T03:13:56Z",
                "status": "True",
                "type": "Initialized"
            },
            {
                "lastProbeTime": null,
                "lastTransitionTime": "2019-12-18T03:14:02Z",
                "status": "True",
                "type": "Ready"
            },
            {
                "lastProbeTime": null,
                "lastTransitionTime": "2019-12-18T03:14:02Z",
                "status": "True",
                "type": "ContainersReady"
            },
            {
                "lastProbeTime": null,
                "lastTransitionTime": "2019-12-18T03:13:56Z",
                "status": "True",
                "type": "PodScheduled"
            }
        ],
        "containerStatuses": [
            {
                "containerID": "docker://13780475170fa2c0d8e616ba1a3b1554d31f404cc0a597877e790cbf01838e63",
                "image": "gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue",
                "imageID": "docker-pullable://gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64@sha256:1ecc9fb2c871302fdb57a25e0c076311b7b352b0a9246d442940ca8fb4efe229",
                "lastState": {},
                "name": "queue",
                "ready": true,
                "restartCount": 0,
                "started": true,
                "state": {
                    "running": {
                        "startedAt": "2019-12-18T03:14:02Z"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "hostIP": "192.168.64.3",
        "phase": "Running",
        "podIP": "172.17.0.2",
        "podIPs": [
            {
                "ip": "172.17.0.2"
            }
        ],
        "qosClass": "BestEffort",
        "startTime": "2019-12-18T03:13:56Z"
    }
}
```

How do you checker what port a pod is listening on with kubectl?

**Update**

If I ssh into the pod and run `netstat -tulpn` as suggested in the comments I get:

```
$ kubectl exec -it queue-pfmq2 -- sh
~ $ netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/kuard
```

But this method is not using `kubectl`.

Comment: According to the pod YAML you've shown, the pod isn't listening on any port in particular.  (This is common enough for worker-type containers that pull tasks from a job queue.)  I think you've found all of the data that's there to be found using `kubectl` alone.

Comment: But when I `kubectl port-forward $QUEUE_POD 8080:8080`...it shows on `8080`. The kuard image is like an all in 1 demo, that has a queue and frontend built in.

Comment: shell into the pod and try running netstat -tulpn gives you all the ports open.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your container image has a port opened during the build (looks like port 8080 in your case) using the [EXPOSE command in the Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose). Since the exposed port is baked into the image, k8s does not keep track of this open port since k8s does not need to take steps to open it.

Since k8s is not responsible for opening the port, you won't be able to find the listening port using kubectl or checking the pod YAML

Answer (score 17):

Try the combination of both **kubectl** and your Linux command to get the **Port** container is listening on:

```
kubectl exec <pod name here> -- netstat -tulpn
```

Further you can pipe this result with `grep` to narrow the findings if required eg.

```
kubectl exec <pod name here> -- netstat -tulpn | grep "search string"
```

**Note:** It will work only if your container's base image supports the command `netstat`. and as per your **Update** section it seems it supports.
Above solution is nothing but a smart use of the commands you have used in two parts first to `exec` the container in interactive mode using `-it` second in the container to list the listening port.

Answer (score 4):

One answer suggested to run `netstat` inside the container.
This only works if `netstat` is part of the container's image.

As an alternative, you can run `netstat` on the host executing it in the container's network namespace..

Get the container's process ID on the host (this is the application running inside the container). Then change to the container's network namespace (run as `root` on the host):

```
host# PS1='container# ' nsenter -t <PID> -n
```

Modifying the `PS1` environment variable is used to show a different prompt while you are in the container's network namespace.

Get the listening ports in the container:

```
container# netstat -na
....
container# exit
```

Comment: host doesn't have netstat neither..

Comment: Do you have a way to get the container's process ID without exec'ing into it? Otherwise I'd just install and run `netstat` in the container if I'm already there

Answer (score 1):

If who created the image added the right Openshift label then you can use the following command (unfortunately your image does not have the label) :

```
skopeo inspect docker://image-url:tag | grep expose-service
```

e.g.

```
skopeo inspect docker://quay.io/redhattraining/loadtest:v1.0 | grep expose-service
```

output:

```
"io.openshift.expose-services": "8080:http"
```

So 8080 is the port exposed by the image

Hope this helps

Answer (score -4):

normally. a container will able to run curl . so you can use curl to check whether a port is open.

```
   for port in 8080 50000 443 8443;do curl -I - connect-timeout 1 127.0.0.1:$port;done
```

this can be run with sh.

Comment: there will be many ports, how do we identify the port pod is running on